# Linking AMCharts bullets with an outside content slider

Tags: html, amcharts

I have a basic horizontal content slider, and I have a very basic line chart that I created in the live editor and just copied into my HTML. Now the challenge is to link each bullet on the graph with a different slide in my content slider. I know that I have to add an eventListener, but I'm not sure how to link each bullet to a different slide.

```
        <div class="sp-slideshow">

            <input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label>

            <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" />
            <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>

            <input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-3" />
            <label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label>

            <input id="button-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-4" />
            <label for="button-4" class="button-label-4"></label>

            <input id="button-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-5" />
            <label for="button-5" class="button-label-5"></label>

            <label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label>
            <label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label>
            <label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>
            <label for="button-4" class="sp-arrow sp-a4"></label>
            <label for="button-5" class="sp-arrow sp-a5"></label>

            <div class="sp-content">
                <div class="sp-parallax-bg"></div>
                <ul class="sp-slider clearfix">
                    <li><img src="images/image1.png" alt="image01" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image2.png" alt="image02" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image3.png" alt="image03" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image4.png" alt="image04" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image5.png" alt="image05" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- sp-content -->

        </div><!-- sp-slideshow -->
```

Comment: Hi Mari. Basic question: How do you navigate in the content slider?

Comment: To the content slider? meaning on the page itself? You will just scroll down as it will be a parralax one page layout? but at this stage it's just a html demo that I'm busy working on. But navigating through the slides you have arrows 'next' and 'prev' but I also wan't my bullets in my amcharts graph to work as navigation. It's suppose to have a "timeline" feel, if you can see where I am getting at

Comment: . I don't know if this wil be possible. I'm trying to create a different class or id for each slide at this stage and maybe create a onclick event to getElementById. don't know if I'm wasting my time. I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: My intention was, if you're navigating by index of the content or what. Because how should the bullet know where to navigate. Because getting click events on graphitems is easy, but i need some info about the "mapping" of the navigation. So do i just need the index of the dataPoint and that's sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should pretty much fit your needs: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e23ztt9y/2/).
The important code is:

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(e){
    alert(e.item.index); // replace with navigation
});
```

You **must** use bullets, otherwise it won't work. If you don't want them to be displayed use: `bulletAlpha: 0`
Hope this helps. ;)

**Edit:**
Based on your code in the last comment, i would recommend to use some kind of mapping.
This makes your code easier to read and reusable.
Here's an example:

```
buttonMap = ["#button-1", "#button-2", "#button-3", ...];

chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(e) {
    $(buttonMap[e.item.index]).click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the trouble but I think you are understanding me wrong.

Comment: I have a page in my website, in this page a have a full width content slider. underneath this content slider I have my am charts line chat which will have more of a timeline feel. so my labels will be dates and one you click on the dates or the bullet or whatever the content slider will go to the slide which goes with that date. I wish I could try and work up a fiddle for you to show you, but jsfiddle gets frightened when there is to much code. I'm sorry, you must think that I am a pain in the "behind"

Comment: something like this except my timeline will be an am charts graph.

Comment: @Mari 
 
I've updated the fiddle as it was not working. But i still don't get what you want or whats wrong with my answer. You requested an event for the click. And then you can just do sth like this: navigateSliderTo(index).

Comment: I'm still trying to get it to work. Ill let you know once I figure it out, for some reason it's not linking to the slides.

Comment: Could you tell me how you're planning to navigate? With a function and an index?

Comment: chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(event){
 console.log("clickGraphItem");
    var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-2');
 $(tester1).click();

});

Comment: this is what I have and it work, but getting each bullet to link to a different slide is not working. I have navigation buttons at the bottom of my slider and I'm trying to use them to navigate because they have individual ID's

Comment: A fiddle would make things much easier. What about mapping the IDs with the index of the data point clicked?

Comment: How do I do that? I can email you the file if you want to look at it. Don't know if you have privacy issues.

Comment: chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(e){
  if(e.item.index == 0) {
   var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
   $(tester1).click();
  }
  if(e.item.index == 1) {
   var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-2');
   $(tester1).click();
  }     
  if(e.item.index == 2) {
   var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-3');
   $(tester1).click();
  }
  if(e.item.index == 3) {
   var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-4');
   $(tester1).click();
  }
  if(e.item.index == 4) {
   var tester1 = document.getElementById('button-5');
   $(tester1).click();
  }    
});

Comment: Sorry only saw it now. I added it and it works like a bomb. You are a genius. Thank you for all your help.